# Stack Overflow Careers: Inconsistent Labeling on "Fill Out Your Profile" Page During Signup

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page, sign-up

Page: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/create

The Text on the Page Says **By clicking "continue", you agree to our privacy policy and terms of service.**

But the actual button says **Get Started**, not **Continue**. (There is no button labeled "Continue" on the page.)

[image: Marked Up Screenshot of Inconsistency on Fill Out Your Profile Page of Stack Overflow Careers during Signup Process]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice catch! That button *used* to say "continue" but I changed it and I am not very attentive. As of the next push to production, the sentence will actually match the button.